# Return single value based on conditional CASE

Tags: mysql

I have no background with MySQL and have not been able to find the appropriate stepping stones to accomplish writing this particular query.

**Objective:**

I have created a report that shows the approval status of artwork per page. Artists have to access the proof however to determine if there is any markup/notes on each page. I want to add single column to the report that will have one of three string values per page for each proof. The string will either be "Yes", No", or "Missed" based on certain conditions.

Each proof can have multiple pages. Each page can have multiple marks (think of drawing a circle around something). Each mark can have multiple notes. This is where, for me, things get hazy. I am aware of the need to avoid RBAR queries, but I am unsure how to query against multiple comments and then marks by page.

**Conditions:**

This is the RBAR query I have for handling the notes/comments. This is fine for dealing with each comment, but obviously on a report there is no reason to see each comment row.

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN note IS NULL OR ' ' AND deleted = FALSE 
    THEN 'Missed' ELSE 'Yes' 
    END AS 'Comment' 
FROM rvm_comment
```

Knowing that a mark can have multiple comments, I need to determine if any rows in rvm_comment.note are NOT NULL or contain just a space, ' '. If so, the mark is represented as "Yes". Otherwise the mark would be "Missed".

This should then be condensed/nested in a manner that each mark is compared.
If any mark on a page is "Yes" then output in that row would be "Yes". Otherwise, "Missed".

If this doesn't make sense, hopefully the following information will shed some light.

**Tables and Relationships:**
[image: Tables and Joins]

DSE_OBJECT Table:

This table is associated with a request that a proof can be attached to. The ID is the PK.

RVM_REVIEW_OBJECT Table:

This table is essentially the proof instance itself. A proof can have any number of pages (min 1).  ID is the PK, review_object is the FK.

RVM_MARK Table:

This table contains information on marks that are added to a proof, including the page they exist on. ID is the PK, review_object is the FK. (NOT LISTED) Deleted is used to prevent returning results where a mark is deleted by the user. rvm_mark.deleted = FALSE

RVM_COMMENT Table:

This table is where the notes (strings) are stored. Deleted is used to prevent returning results where a note is deleted by the user (rvm_comment.deleted = FALSE). There is a flaw in the system where a comment can be created but if the user doesn't hit "enter" on their keyboard after typing the text is not saved in to the DB. This is why we need to test for NULL in rvm_comment.note.

**Raw Data for Testing and Summary**: [Dropbox with CSVs for the tables](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tdlne47sdr01qbd/AADymyMIXwAv0tjtvJkw6_hva?dl=0)

As a courtesy I have included some raw data in CSV form for anyone will to try it out. (click Dropbox link above).

So, to summarize again. I am trying to write a query that will condense those tables to a single string (AS Comment),for each rvm_mark.page_no. The string is based on a) whether or not rvm_comment.note is NULL or ' ', and b) whether any rvm_mark.id that has matching rvm_mark.page_no, has rvm_comment.note that isn't NULL.

---

**EDIT UPDATE 12/14/16:**

Thanks to Barmar I was able to take a step towards the final result. I am currently stuck on trying to return the string 'No' for any situations where there are no comments. This should only be when rvm_review_object.id does not have a matching value in rvm_mark.review_object.

```
SELECT rvm_review_object.dse_object_id, rvm_review_object.id, 
T_Mark.creator, T_Mark.review_object,
  CASE WHEN T_Mark.review_object IS NULL THEN 'No'
  ELSE T_Mark.Comment
  END AS Comment
FROM rvm_review_object

LEFT JOIN(
SELECT rvm_mark.review_object, rvm_mark.creator, rvm_mark.id, 
  CASE WHEN MAX(T_Comment.Comment = 'Yes') = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE 'Missed'
  END AS Comment
FROM rvm_mark

LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT rvm_comment.mark,
      CASE WHEN MAX((rvm_comment.note IS NULL OR rvm_comment.note = '') 
        AND rvm_comment.deleted = FALSE) = 1
      THEN 'Missed'
      ELSE 'Yes'
      END AS Comment
  FROM rvm_comment
  GROUP BY rvm_comment.mark) AS T_Comment

ON T_Comment.mark = rvm_mark.id
WHERE rvm_mark.deleted = FALSE
GROUP BY rvm_mark.review_object) AS T_Mark

ON T_Mark.review_object = rvm_review_object.id
WHERE rvm_review_object.creator != T_Mark.creator
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the query by `mark`. You can then use `MAX()` to determine if any of the rows in the group match the condition.

```
SELECT mark, 
    CASE WHEN MAX((note IS NULL OR note = '') AND deleted = FALSE) = 1
            THEN 'Missed'
         ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS Comment
FROM rvm_comment
GROUP BY mark
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I will try this out asap and I'll let you know how things pan out. I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Thank you again. I have updated the above to try and move to the next step, which is to have only a single mark per page (rvm_mark.page_no). The EDIT is included at the bottom and I am getting a syntax error for the last line, GROUP BY.

Comment: You can't use an aggregate function like `MAX()` in the `WHERE` clause. Also, the argument to `MAX()` can't be a subquery that returns multiple columns.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do in the second query, but my guess is you should be using a `JOIN` with the subquery, not putting it into the `WHERE` clause like that.

Comment: Okay, I will give that a whirl. The goal is to do that same thing with the rvm_comment.note and rvm_comment.mark with rvm_mark.page_no. I only need one value returned based on all the marks on that page. My thought process was that it should be a sub query.

Comment: I updated the current state of the query, Syntactically it is working, but it is not the result I need. Jumping back to your original query, that works at the note level, but I need to do the same thing now with the table "above" it, rvm_mark. rvm_mark contains the column page_no, where it should only be a single row per page, for the 'Yes'/'Missed'.

Comment: You should post a new question.

Comment: I updated the query again. This is currently working as intended with the exception of the outer most CASE statement. I'm not sure if I need to do another join or a subquery in order to get the string showing. This should occur when rvm_review_object.id doesn't have a matching value in rvm_mark.review_object.

Comment: You should post a new question.